# Is there a way to activate JavaScript each time an HTML class is encountered?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to JavaScript, and I can't find this specific questions anywhere else, so this is probably not the correct way to do this. Still, I wanted to put this out there. I want to make list items under the ID upcomingEvents to be hidden based on if the date has already passed. The idea is I would have a list of 20 or so events on an HTML page, and the months/days in the classes upcomingEventDay and upcomingEventMonth. I got this script to work in an external .js file for the first instance of the classes in my HTML doc:

```js
today = new Date(); 
eventDay = document.querySelector(".upcomingEventDay");
eventMonth = document.querySelector(".upcomingEventMonth");
listedEvent = document.querySelector("#upcomingEvents li");

if ( today.getDate() > eventDay.innerText && (today.getMonth()+1) !== eventMonth.innerText) {
  //dont display upcomingEvents.li
  listedEvent.classList.add("d-none");
}
```

However, for every subsequent instance of the class, the script is ignored (here is a sample of the HTML):

```html
<ul id="upcomingEvents">
<li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">3</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">15</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 1</strong></a></li>
<li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">3</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">16</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 2</strong></a></li>
<li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">3</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">25</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 3</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I make the script apply to every instance of those classes in the HTML document? I had the idea that I could give each list item a unique ID, but that would be super inefficient

Comment: Assuming the HTML is static, move your script code to a `function` that runs after `DOMContentLoaded`. Generally speaking, you should never manipulate the DOM (using `querySelector` or `getElementById`) in a script unless you know the `<script>` element is located _after_ the elements you want to use _or_ if the script will run after `DOMContentLoaded` - or if you know it will run with `defer`.

Comment: please add a workign code snippet (**ctrl + m**) whoing all necessary code to reproduce the error. Also if you wannt to apply or remove a class to all elements you should use `querySelectorAll`. Thise however willr etrun an array which you need to cycle through with `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Two most important things to note:

1. Always run js after all elements that you need are loaded. One good way is to run js on page load.
2. When selecting elements that can be multiple, you either need to run a loop over them to process each or select one of them to process. Directly comparing values will not result correctly.

You can take a reference of how to do that in the following code. I have broken down steps to make them clear and eas to understand.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var today = new Date();

  var eventList = document.getElementById("upcomingEvents");
  var listedEvent = eventList.getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (var i = 0; i < listedEvent.length; i++) {
    var eventDay = listedEvent[i].getElementsByClassName("upcomingEventDay")[0];
    var eventMonth = listedEvent[i].getElementsByClassName("upcomingEventMonth")[0];
    if (today.getDate() > parseInt(eventDay.innerText, 10) && (today.getMonth() + 1) <= parseInt(eventMonth.innerText, 10)) {
      //dont display upcomingEvents.li
      listedEvent[i].hidden = true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<ul id="upcomingEvents">
  <li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">3</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">15</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 1</strong></a></li>
  <li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">3</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">16</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 2</strong></a></li>
  <li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">3</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">25</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 3</strong></a></li>
    <li><span class="upcomingEventMonth">4</span>/<span class="upcomingEventDay">30</span>, 2021 | <a href="#" target="_blank"><strong>Test Event 4</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

Update: Use of "hidden" attribute instead of css

Comment: HTML has an attribute for `.d-none`: `hidden`. Use it.

Comment: @connexo I wanted this to be an example where the OP can see how other related (if any) classes can be added. Also, OP intended to use a given class instead of an attribute.

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi I'd wager the OP is ignorant of the `hidden` attribute though. In this context I see no harm in using a _better solution_ in an answer.

Comment: @connexo Updated now. Thanks!